# Graphite installation in a docker container - volume query

Tags: monitoring, docker, graphite

I am installing graphite via a docker container.
I have seen that whisper files should not be saved in the container.

So I will be using a data volume from docker to save these on the host machine.

My question is is there anything else I should be saving on the host (I know this is subjective so I guess Im looking for recommendations on whats important)?
Don't believe I need configuration e.g. carbon conf as this will come from my installation

So I'm thinking are there any other files from graphite I need (e.g log files etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your reason for keeping log files? Though you do need the directory structure in place. Logging defaults to `/opt/graphite/storage/logs`. In here you have `carbon-cache/` and `webapp/` directories. The log directory for the webapp is set in the config- `local_settings.py`, whereas carbon uses `carbon.conf`. The configs are well documented so you can look into them for specific information.

Apart from configs that are generated during installation the only other 'file' crucial for the webapp to work is `graphite.db` in the `/opt/graphtie/storage`. It is used internally by the django webapp for housekeeping information such as user-auth etc. It gets generated by `python manage.py --syncdb` so i believe you can generate it again at the target system.

Comment: thanks erbdex. Log files kept for trouble shooting if the need ever arises. Think will create data volume at the graphite storage level